# MVC-friendly approach to Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller, core-data, architecture

Ok so I am pretty new to Core Data, and I am now starting to dig into it more and I have a question about the correct way to implement it.

I have a parentViewController object that is loaded from the appDelegate. The parentView is a view that sets up a paging UIScrollView for three more viewController objects, it's children. The view loads up and I  can page between the three views beautifully.

All three of the views need to have a significant amount of data exchange with Core Data. Should I pass the reference of the managedObjectContext into each different view within the parentView so that all the views can pull from and write to Core Data themselves? Or should I keep the reference in the parentView, and let the children pass the requests to the parent to handle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have typically used a third option, at least for simple applications with a single persistence store that I access throughout the lifetime of the app: Make the managedObjectContext a property of your application delegate, and initialize it when the application is started. Then, you can access it from anywhere in your application using something like:

```
MyApplicationDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [delegate managedObjectContext];
```

This approach is not ideal for all designs and architectures, but I'm finding it works well for me and keeps my code relatively clean.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers should never communicate directly with each other in MVC. Any data that needs to be shared between controllers should be shared through the model layer, of which the MOC is a part. So, ideally, you should pass the MOC to every object that needs to use it. Perfectly OK to have multiple objects reading/writing to the same MOC simultaneously; respects principles of Dependency Injection; and probably less code to write.

Comment: That is a restrictive generalisation. What about the case when the user selects an item from a master view controller and then a detail view controller is displayed to edit the item? The master view controller would typically communicate with the detail view controller to set which item to edit.

Comment: @RobinSummerhill: In that case the controllers are merely passing necessary model objects back and forth -- nothing wrong with that. What is *not* happening is, one controller is not trying to accomplish some result, via another controller. Each controller is responsible for itself only. I should have been more clear.